# How to setup email notifications for AWS operational issues

Tags: amazon-web-services

Yesterday our infrastructure started throwing lots of connection errors. We started debugging and the more we looked, the more perplexing the issue appeared to be; until someone noticed the bell icon (Alerts) on the AWS page had an orange dot on it.

Behold! there were lots of AWS operational issues in our availability region that AWS were fixing.

To avoid this situation in the future I wanted to subscribe to these 'Alert' so we get an email notification.

Does anyone know how to set up an email alert for AWS operational issues in the specified region?

Much to my astonishment, there was no obvious way to set this up.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to subscribe RSS feed on [AWS Service Health Dashboard](https://status.aws.amazon.com/).

If you want customized stuffs, you can checkout [AWS Personal Health Dashbaord](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/phd/). It shows your AWS services and whether they are experiencing issues.

This [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/ug/cloudwatch-events-health.html) provides a really comprehensive guide on how to setup alerts. Checkout this [aws-health-tools](https://github.com/aws/aws-health-tools) github repository for fully functional examples.